# django ManyToManyField serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

i'm new to django. The version i'm using is 1.11.2

I have a a schema like this.

There are many "designs" and each design can have any number of "patterns".

my design model is like below

```
from django.db import models
from products.models import Product

class Design(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My design serializer is like below

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Design
from rest_framework import serializers
from patterns.models import Pattern

class DesignsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   patterns = DesignPatternSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
   class Meta:
      depth     = 1
      model = Design
      fields = ('id','name','patterns')
      read_only_fields = ('id','name','patterns')
```

The view for designs is as below

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Design
from .serializers import DesignsSerializer
from rest_framework import generics, filters

# Create your views here.
class ListDesignsByProducId(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = DesignsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
       return Design.objects.filter(product_id__exact  = self.kwargs.get('product_id'))
```

My pattern model is like below.

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date
from designs.models import Design

class Pattern(models.Model):
    design_id = models.ManyToManyField(Design)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My pattern serializer is as below

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Pattern
class PatternSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:            
        depth   = 1
        model = Pattern
        fields = ('id','design_id','name')
        read_only_fields =('id','design_id','name')
```

Right now the api would return the details of the designs and it's associated products. 
I would also like to get an array of patterns associated with the design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `DesignsSerializer` you referred to the **patterns** by the name `patterns` without defining it in your models.

From the Django REST Framework [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations):

> You'll normally want to ensure that you've set an appropriate
>   `related_name` argument on the relationship, that you can use as the
>   field name.

In your `Pattern` model:

```
class Pattern(models.Model):
    design_id = models.ManyToManyField(Design, related_name='patterns')
    ...
```

Comment: i will try this during the week end and get back to you